Regedit is not working when I'm trying to change the display language on windows 11
My laptop display language is china because it is from my brother. My problem is I'm trying to change the display language on regedit but its not working. The only change was the default and the install language is not changing. In my default it was 0409 in the install language is 0804. My windows is a home single.
What can I do to change the install language because I'm not really familiar with this

You should be able to change language without using regedit. Normally by using settings.

Why are you trying to change the display language by manipulating the registry?

You can change the Windows language in the GUI using Settings > Time & Language > Language & Region. To see the new language everywhere, you have to both 1) click Add a Language and 2) use Administrative Language Settings to set the new language for the welcome screen, new user accounts, and non-Unicode programs.
